# Including a Python dependency in a Ruby gem

Tags: python, ruby

I have a small Python script that has a dependency on the `scipy` library and a few others. It exposes a few methods: `weather_prediction`, `current_temperature`, and so on.

I would like to make this script callable from a Ruby gem, and wrap the Python methods in similar Ruby methods so that consumers of the gem can interface with Ruby, not Python.

Ruby has the ability to have C extensions, but that's not really what I'm after here; I'd rather just have a way to talk to the Python directly. Is that possible?

Comment: Possibly https://rubygems.org/gems/rubypython - although I have no experience with it, and don't know whether it will support SciPy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow-up: I eventually decided that this was forcing a square peg in a round hole. We now just run the Python dependency as a HTTP service and call it that way.